# How to solve File Movement database table with similar type CURRENT, IN and OUT offices?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, database-design

I am designing a database for tracking files traveling among many offices. Each file movement must store office name from which file is received and office name to which file has been sent.

I have created a table called **tbl_offices** and populated with **id** & **office_name** pair.

I have created another table called **tbl_file_movement** with **id** as primary key and two columns named **recv_from** and **sent_to**. Both columns (recv_from and sent_to) store relevant ids of office from **tbl_offices**. Other columns store receiving date and sent date.

Is there anything wrong?

To get names of offices against the office id, I wrote a query as follows:

```
SELECT id, recv_from AS Recive_From_ID, sent_to AS Sent_To_ID
FROM tbl_file_movement
JOIN tbl_offices ON recv_from = tbl_offices.id
```

What should I add to SELECT statement to get office names from tbl_offices against ids?

Comment: *Is there anything wrong?* Of course. How do you want to identify the filename of the file whose transfer is registered in certain row of `tbl_file_movement` table?

Comment: So far, it sounds like the schema is OK.  But we can't fully judge a schema until we know all the queries to be performed.

Comment: tbl_file_movement  table has some more fields stored in it like file_id through which we can find actual file name. For simplicity, I intentionally not showing other fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understood your question, is that you want to replace the ID on the file movement table with the office name. I have written a query that will do such:

```
SELECT tbl_file_movement.id,
       (SELECT office_name
        FROM   tbl_offices
        WHERE  id = recv_from) AS Receive_From_Office_Name,
       (SELECT office_name
        FROM   tbl_offices
        WHERE  id = sent_to)   AS Sent_To_Office_Name
FROM   tbl_file_movement
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/feabf/1)

*Edit updated link*

Comment: 2 correlated queries for each row of the base table? good bye, performance...

Comment: Hi Rory, can you please suggest to improve the performance?

Comment: Mushtaq, handling performance depends on your use case. Hard to give solid insight without more information.

Comment: But if you need to run this query often, perhaps consider adding this data to a table. It will require more memory but improve performance.

Comment: Thanks Rory, I will definitely consider. Actually , I am new in DB design. In first instance I want to create a basic type DB and then will handle other  issues.